# Can 대명사 (pronouns) be syntactically distinguished from 명사 (nouns)?

Tags: grammar

대명사 includes personal pronouns like 나, 그, and demonstrative pronouns like 그것, 저것.  In some analyses, 대명사 are a separate part of speech from 명사, while other analyses, they are a subcategory of 명사.  What I want to know is if there are syntactical grounds for considering them separate, or if there are only semantic grounds.

In English, there is good reason to consider pronouns a separate part of speech than nouns.  There are syntactic restrictions on pronouns that don't apply to nouns.  For example, we can modify nouns, but not pronouns<sup>1</sup>:

> Beautiful place
>
> X Beautiful She

But in Korean, it is possible to modify 대명사:

> 엽기적인 그녀

So are there any other ways in which 명사 and 대명사 need to be treated differently syntactically?

<sup>1</sup> [with exceptions, of course.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288357/can-an-attributive-adjective-come-before-pronouns)

Answer (score 2):

There's no syntactic difference that differentiates nouns from pronouns that I know of. But it should be mentioned that some common pronouns have particles fused into their bodies, such as 나 + 이(subject marker) -> 내, 그거 + 이(s.m.) -> 그게, 이리 + 로 -> 일로 etc. This does not happen for regular nouns.